# How to find sigma-algebra over omega3 generated by the log-return ln(S2/S1) and ln(S3/S2)?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, finance

I calculated {S2/S1} = {u, u*u/d, d, d*d/u}, and then get ln(S2/S1)= {ln(u),ln(u*u/d), ln(d),ln( d*d/u)}. 
I am not sure my way of doing this question is right, because i m confuse about how to get its sigma-algebra.

Could someone tell me whether this way is right or not?

Comment: What is $\Omega_3$? What $S_1$? $S_2$? $d$? $u$? ... you must give some more details, otherwise it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: omega 3 means the three-period binomial model.

Comment: and S_1 is the first-period result, which have two outcome S_0*u and S_0*d. u means the stock increase, d means the stock decrease.